# clean split of filepath into it's components

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a path into its components in a pythonic way.

**Example:**

```
path = /drive/dir/anotherdir/finaldir/
```

**Approach:**

```
splitted = path.split(os.path.sep)
>>> ['', 'drive', 'dir', 'anotherdir', 'finaldir', '']
```

**Wanted Output:**

```
>>> ['drive', 'dir', 'anotherdir', 'finaldir']
```

Is there a cleaner way so that there are no empty string entries? It's easy to get around with slicing but it just adds unwanted noise. I looked into the **os.path** module and the only splitters are:

```
os.path.split(path)
os.path.splitdrive(path)
os.path.splitext(path)
os.path.splitunc(path)
```

P.S.: i am not looking for a solution i just want to make sure if there is a solution i didn't take intto account.

Comment: You do realize that `/drive/dir/anotherdir/finaldir/` is *different from* `drive/dir/anotherdir/finaldir/`, right?

Comment: Don't get the point... i know that they are different, what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that the result you're asking for makes them indistinguishable, and hoping that you'll explain why that's OK.

Comment: I expect that a fullpath starts with */* and ends with an */* So why should i care about distinguishing between those when i have a strong assumption like that?

Comment: Because your assumption might be wrong? This is how bugs are formed. I hate helping people make bugs.

Comment: It's not an assumption but it's a rule in our work environment and i don't think that there is something wrong with relying on those rules.

Answer (score 2):

try this maybe?

```
path.strip('/').split('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

What [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) is saying is that your *Wanted Output* is invalid, given the possible values `path` could take. When talking about paths, the OS has some conventions regarding how to resolve a path string to a file or directory.

Consider the following code:

```
def toComponents(path):
    return path.split('/')


def fromComponents(components):
    return '/'.join(components)

# specialToComponents takes a path and returns
# the components relative to the / folder or
# if the path is relative, it returns the components
# Use at your own risk.
def specialToComponents(path):
    return path.strip('/').split('/')
```

Suppose you have two paths:

- `path = /drive/dir/anotherdir/finaldir/` This is an absolute path, which tells the reader and the OS that the file is located inside the `/` folder, inside the `path` folder and so on, until `finaldir/`
- `path = drive/dir/anotherdir/finaldir/` This is a relative path. It conventionally means relative to the program's current directory. It says go to the current directory, then go to `drive` then `dir` and so on, until `finaldir/`.

What you're trying to do is read absolute paths as relative ones and relative ones as relative ones, which is great, if only it doesn't cause headaches for you when someone tries to run your code against an absolute path.